# Using array of object create a new array that contains all the objects from the original array of object that have a numerical value greater than 15

Tags: javascript, arrays

help please, i have this array of object and must to create a new array that contains all the objects from the original array of object that have a numerical value greater than 15.
how can i do this ? which method a must to use ?

```
const names = [
  { name: 'Anna' },
  { num: 27 },
  { name: 'Valeria', age: 20},
  { secondname: 'Wilson' },
  { age: 12, name: 'Max' },
  { weight:'50kg', height: '172cm', name: 'Nick' }
]
```

i try to use filter,but it should see any field that has a number value not just age or num

```
const number = arr.filter(a => a.num || a.age > 15);
console.log(number);
```

Comment: what is a numerical value? a number?

Comment: in this case as a result i must to have this one: { num: 27 },
  { name: 'Valeria', age: 20}, but if i add one field like {a= 20}, this is also must be return

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you like to get only numbers, you chould check the values of the object with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

```js
const
    names = [{ name: 'Anna' }, { num: 27 }, { name: 'Valeria', age: 20 }, { secondname: 'Wilson' }, { age: 12, name: 'Max' }, { weight: '50kg', height: '172cm', name: 'Nick' }],
    result = names.filter(o => Object
        .values(o)
        .some(v => typeof v === 'number' && v > 15)
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: can you tell me what other method can be used besides some?

Comment: [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) is kind of same, but works opposite. for this use case `some` is better, because it is easier to understand, like in prosa: if some item is in the array which match, take ... `every` is not very intuitive to use it here.

Comment: I said before that `every` is like `some` with negative condition.

Comment: @ITgoldman, yes i saw it, then you deleted it ...